# Plotting a table with varying step sizes

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, homework

how can I plot the below green curve? Is there any way I could manipulate the step sizes?

[image]

This is my current code:

```
s1 = Plot[{Table[1/2 (c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 x^2]), {c, -30, 30, 2}], 
Table[1/2 (c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 x^2]), {c, -30, 30, 2}]}, {x, -30, 30},
PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-15, 15}}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
ParametricPlot[
  Table[sign (i {Cos[x], Sin[x]} + {0, i}), {i, 1, 20, 2}, {sign, {-1, 1}}],
  {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Green
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then adjust the `PlotRange`, the range of and pitch of the values of $i$ to your desired results:

```
ParametricPlot[
  Table[sign (i {Cos[x], Sin[x]} + {0, i}), {i, 1, 15, 1}, {sign, {-1, 1}}],
  {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Green,
  PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-15, 15}}, ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I need to keep the equations 

    1/2 (c - Sqrt[c^2 - 4 x^2]) 
    1/2 (c + Sqrt[c^2 - 4 x^2] 

as this is a math assignment. What I'm mainly looking for is to have plot evaluate the equation at a value of c that will make it a straight line across the x-axis (like in my above picture with the red and green curves) without it appearing messy.